# How to call Function<Void,Void>.apply()?

Tags: java, guava

I have a method which receives a `Function<Void, Void>` (A Guava Function, not a Java 8 Function):

```
public void foo(Function<Void, Void> algo) {

  algo.apply();  // <- Compile error. 

}
```

I have a compile error because `algo.apply()` takes a Void instance as argument but I don't know how to instantiate one.

What is the syntax for this use case?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the interface `Runnable` for this, not `Function`. A `Function` is intended to take an input and produce an output, ideally without side effects. `Runnable` is intended to run some code, taking neither an input nor returning an output and necessarily having side effects unless it does nothing.

Comment: `Function`s should not have side effects, and a `Function<Void, Void>` without side effects can only return `null`.  Please use `Runnable` here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Void` *instance* is rather contradictory. Try passing `null`. If you don't get a `NullPointerException` then that's probably the correct thing to do.

(Else read the documentation if there is any).

Comment: But do check carefully with a debugger. My suggestion comes from the `return null` idiom that you need to use when using a `Callable` that doesn't return anything.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: As there are no instances of `Void` (unless you make one via reflection or `Unsafe` :D:D), `null` is the only choice. It looks like someone is misusing `Function` for something purely non-functional (just side-effects).